# Uproot issue: Trouble making sense of a particular 'branch'

Tags: python, root-framework, uproot

I have a root file open in python as such:

```
file = uproot.open('C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\test.root')
print(file.keys())
[b'evts;1', b'miscAccum;1', b'cal;1', b'configstr;1', b'time;1', b'Plugs;1', b'acc;1']
print(file[b'Plugs'].keys())
[b'veto;1', b'miscAccum;1', b'calfine;1']
```

All good but if I try to explore the time branch with `print(file[b'time'].keys())` I get an error saying

> 'TVectorT_3c_double_3e_' object has no attribute 'keys'

How can I explore the value(s) within this branch?

Comment: What do you get when you use `print(file[b'time'])` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories ([uproot.ReadOnlyDirectory](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.reading.ReadOnlyDirectory.html)) and TTrees ([uproot.TTree](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TTree.TTree.html)) are objects that can initiate more reading, so they are navigable as Mappings with `keys()` and square-bracket syntax (`__getitem__`).

This object evidently has class type `TVectorT_3c_double_3e_` (a Python model, [uproot.Model](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.model.Model.html), of C++ class `TVectorT<double>`). Some objects like this have custom "behaviors," which are user-friendly properties and methods. For example, the model of `TParameter<double>` has a `value` property (see [uproot.behaviors.TParameter](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.behaviors.TParameter.TParameter_3c_floating_3e_.html)). This one does not.

When Uproot reads an object and does not have custom behaviors, you can still access its C++ private member data through the [uproot.Model.member](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.model.Model.html#member) method or the [uproot.Model.all_members](https://uproot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uproot.model.Model.html#all-members) property (dict). In fact, these are how high-level behaviors get implemented: the reading of C++ private member data is automatic, but humans have to design high-level APIs by writing functions to access them in a more user-friendly way, something that's happened for `TParameter<double>` but not `TVectorT<double>` yet.

(To first order, ROOT has infinitely many classes.)

So, to be explicit, do

```py
file["time"].all_members
```

and see what you get.

---

One other thing, unrelated to that: I noticed that you're using Uproot 3 because all of the keys are `bytes` instead of `str`. Since you're not maintaining a legacy script, you should upgrade to Uproot 4. Since Dec 2020, Uproot 4 is just "uproot":

```sh
pip install uproot awkward
```

(*Usually*, you want Awkward Array as well, so I included that in the pip-install. You might need to `pip uninstall` the versions you have now to get a clean slate.)

The documentation links and interface I described above is all for Uproot 4.

Comment: Thanks Bruh! Totally worked (after I upgraded uproot)